# I'm getting "installed rtl8821ce-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 3" error

Tags: 20.04

I ran `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and got this message:

```
Setting up rtl8821ce-dkms (5.5.2.1-0ubuntu4~20.04.3) ...
Removing old rtl8821ce-5.5.2.1 DKMS files...
Loading new rtl8821ce-5.5.2.1 DKMS files...
Error! DKMS tree already contains: rtl8821ce-5.5.2.1
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.
dpkg: error processing package rtl8821ce-dkms (--configure):
 installed rtl8821ce-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 3
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rtl8821ce-dkms
```

Consequently, I can't use the Wi-Fi. I can't run the VirtualBox.
I have tried reinstalling Ubuntu 20.04, but it's still the same. I have tried several ways all day but to no avail.

I ran `sudo apt-get autoremove` and got this message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up rtl8821ce-dkms (5.5.2.1-0ubuntu4~20.04.3) ...
Removing old rtl8821ce-5.5.2.1 DKMS files...
Loading new rtl8821ce-5.5.2.1 DKMS files...
Error! DKMS tree already contains: rtl8821ce-5.5.2.1
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.
dpkg: error processing package rtl8821ce-dkms (--configure):
 installed rtl8821ce-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 3
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rtl8821ce-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`
```

I ran `sudo apt-get install -f` and got this message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up rtl8821ce-dkms (5.5.2.1-0ubuntu4~20.04.3) ...
Removing old rtl8821ce-5.5.2.1 DKMS files...
Loading new rtl8821ce-5.5.2.1 DKMS files...
Error! DKMS tree already contains: rtl8821ce-5.5.2.1
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.
dpkg: error processing package rtl8821ce-dkms (--configure):
 installed rtl8821ce-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 3
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rtl8821ce-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What should I do?

Comment: dkms status please. And uname  - r

Comment: `dkms status` rtl8821ce, 5.5.2.1: added. `uname -r` 5.8.0-43-generic
 I think this happened because of error code 1 `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)` help me please

Comment: thank u very much. finally, i ran `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install rtl8821ce-dkms1

Comment: @ardipermana Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Would you please post an answer then set it as accepted. This is QA site, see [about].

Comment: Please post the answer as an *actual* answer and not as a comment - that is **not** what the comment section is for. Then mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to reinstall the package after removing it from your system. Reinstalling solved the error in many of the systems I have tried it. So run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt remove rtl8821ce-dkms
git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce
cd rtl8821ce
chmod +x dkms-install.sh
chmod +x dkms-remove.sh
make
sudo make install
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

Then reboot.

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked like a charm and my install is connected to the internet for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm installing rtl8821ce-dkms_5.5.2.1-**0ubuntu6_all** (not "0ubuntu4_all")  and this works:

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/rtl8821ce/rtl8821ce-dkms_5.5.2.1-0ubuntu6_all.deb

sudo dpkg -i rtl8821ce-dkms_5.5.2.1-0ubuntu6_all.deb
```