# Ubuntu 20.04 stops seeing wifi networks after several minutes

Tags: networking, dual-boot, drivers, wireless, 20.04

I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 11. When I turn the computer on, everything seems to work fine, but after several minutes the WiFi connection drops and there are no visible networks in the WiFi settings anymore (at all, not just the one I was connected to). When I restart the laptop, the WiFi connects automatically as if it had no problems and all the networks available are visible again until the next disconnection.

Other devices connected to the WiFi, as well as the Windows system on the same laptop, do not have such a problem. There are also no problems when I connect to the router using a cable.

I have the following options in the "Additional Drivers" tab of the "Software & Updates" app but choosing neither of them solves the issue:

[Additional drivers window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDf0d.png)

Here is some other information, which I read could be useful:

$ sudo lshw -class network

```
   *-generic                 
        description: Wireless interface
        product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
        vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
        physical id: 0
        bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
        logical name: wlp7s0
        version: ff
        serial: 00:45:e2:0d:3c:8d
        width: 32 bits
        clock: 66MHz
        capabilities: bus_master vga_palette cap_list ethernet physical wireless
        configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_8821ce driverversion=5.11.0-41-generic firmware=N/A latency=255 link=no maxlatency=255 mingnt=255 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
        resources: irq:145 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:a4300000-a430ffff
   *-network
        description: Ethernet interface
        product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
        vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
        physical id: 0
        bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
        logical name: enp8s0
        version: 10
        serial: 00:2b:67:4a:c4:c2
        size: 100Mbit/s
        capacity: 1Gbit/s
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
        configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.11.0-41-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 ip=192.168.178.76 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
        resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a4204000-a4204fff memory:a4200000-a4203fff
```

$ lspci

```
 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
 00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
 00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
 00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
 00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
 00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
 00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
 00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 10)
 00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 10)
 00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
 00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake Mobile PCH SATA AHCI Controller (rev 10)
 00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
 00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #13 (rev f0)
 00:1d.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #14 (rev f0)
 00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO UART Host Controller (rev 10)
 00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM470 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 10)
 00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
 00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
 00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q] (rev a1)
 01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10fa (rev a1)
 06:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
 07:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter (rev ff)
 08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
```

$ rfkill list all

```
 0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
 1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
 2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
 3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

$ lsusb

```
 Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
 Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b6d9 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera
 Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:c024 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio 
 Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

$ dmesg

```
 [  704.116062]  rtw_ops_config+0xa3/0xe0 [rtw88_core]
 [  704.116087]  ieee80211_hw_config+0x99/0x3e0 [mac80211]
 [  704.116188]  ieee80211_recalc_idle+0x27/0x30 [mac80211]
 [  704.116293]  __ieee80211_start_scan+0x376/0x740 [mac80211]
 [  704.116388]  ieee80211_request_scan+0x30/0x50 [mac80211]
 [  704.116482]  ieee80211_scan+0x5c/0xa0 [mac80211]
 [  704.116586]  cfg80211_scan+0x1a5/0x250 [cfg80211]
 [  704.116691]  nl80211_trigger_scan+0x55c/0x660 [cfg80211]
 [  704.116795]  genl_family_rcv_msg_doit.isra.0+0xec/0x150
 [  704.116811]  genl_rcv_msg+0xe5/0x1e0
 [  704.116819]  ? nl80211_send_scan_start+0xa0/0xa0 [cfg80211]
 [  704.116920]  ? genl_family_rcv_msg_doit.isra.0+0x150/0x150
 [  704.116930]  netlink_rcv_skb+0x55/0x100
 [  704.116938]  genl_rcv+0x29/0x40
 [  704.116946]  netlink_unicast+0x1a8/0x250
 [  704.116954]  netlink_sendmsg+0x221/0x440
 [  704.116963]  sock_sendmsg+0x65/0x70
 [  704.116971]  ____sys_sendmsg+0x218/0x290
 [  704.116977]  ? copy_msghdr_from_user+0x5c/0x90
 [  704.116986]  ___sys_sendmsg+0x81/0xc0
 [  704.116994]  ? __check_object_size+0x4d/0x150
 [  704.117001]  ? _copy_to_user+0x31/0x50
 [  704.117063]  ? sock_getsockopt+0x11a/0xc70
 [  704.117075]  ? unix_ioctl+0x9c/0x180
 [  704.117092]  ? sock_do_ioctl+0x43/0x140
 [  704.117104]  ? __cgroup_bpf_run_filter_setsockopt+0xb6/0x3d0
 [  704.117123]  ? __cgroup_bpf_run_filter_getsockopt+0xb4/0x3c0
 [  704.117138]  ? _cond_resched+0x19/0x30
 [  704.117151]  __sys_sendmsg+0x62/0xb0
 [  704.117166]  ? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x3d/0x1a0
 [  704.117182]  __x64_sys_sendmsg+0x1f/0x30
 [  704.117193]  do_syscall_64+0x38/0x90
 [  704.117204]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
 [  704.117216] RIP: 0033:0x7f7cd0dda747
 [  704.117226] Code: 64 89 02 48 c7 c0 ff ff ff ff eb bb 0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa 64 8b 04 25 18 00 00 00 85 c0 75 10 b8 2e 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 51 c3 48 83 ec 28 89 54 24 1c 48 89 74 24 10
 [  704.117234] RSP: 002b:00007fffe28e0348 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 000000000000002e
 [  704.117245] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 000055c7abe99650 RCX: 00007f7cd0dda747
 [  704.117251] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 00007fffe28e0380 RDI: 0000000000000006
 [  704.117257] RBP: 000055c7abecca90 R08: 0000000000000004 R09: 00007f7cd0ea2b80
 [  704.117262] R10: 00007fffe28e0454 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 000055c7abe99560
 [  704.117269] R13: 00007fffe28e0380 R14: 00007fffe28e0454 R15: 000055c7abece780
 [  704.117282] ---[ end trace 74da5af69e3aa44d ]---
 [  704.117293] rtw_8821ce 0000:07:00.0: failed to read ASPM, ret=-5
 [  706.117400] rtw_8821ce 0000:07:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
 [  706.117408] rtw_8821ce 0000:07:00.0: mac power on failed
 [  706.117410] rtw_8821ce 0000:07:00.0: failed to power on mac
 [  706.117412] rtw_8821ce 0000:07:00.0: leave idle state failed
 [  706.117538] rtw_8821ce 0000:07:00.0: failed to leave ips state
 [  706.117542] rtw_8821ce 0000:07:00.0: failed to leave idle state
 [  711.969488] rtw_8821ce 0000:07:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
 [  711.969768] ------------[ cut here ]------------
 [  711.969769] failed to read DBI register, addr=0x0719
 [  711.969793] WARNING: CPU: 8 PID: 282 at drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtw88/pci.c:1174 rtw_dbi_read8.constprop.0+0xaa/0xc0 [rtw88_pci]
 [  711.969801] Modules linked in: ipheth apple_mfi_fastcharge ccm rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_sof snd_hda_codec_generic snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_soc_hdac_hda x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_hda_codec_hdmi coretemp snd_soc_acpi ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel mei_hdcp snd_intel_dspcfg soundwire_intel kvm_intel soundwire_generic_allocation intel_rapl_msr soundwire_cadence snd_hda_codec kvm snd_hda_core snd_hwdep soundwire_bus crct10dif_pclmul rtw88_8821ce ghash_clmulni_intel snd_soc_core rtw88_8821c rtw88_pci aesni_intel snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine rtw88_core crypto_simd cryptd uvcvideo snd_pcm glue_helper nouveau rapl videobuf2_vmalloc snd_seq_midi videobuf2_memops snd_seq_midi_event videobuf2_v4l2 btusb mac80211 snd_rawmidi btrtl btbcm videobuf2_common btintel mxm_wmi
 [  711.969849]  intel_cstate i915 snd_seq drm_ttm_helper joydev bluetooth snd_seq_device videodev ttm snd_timer input_leds intel_wmi_thunderbolt mc wmi_bmof cfg80211 efi_pstore serio_raw drm_kms_helper ecdh_generic ecc cec snd rc_core processor_thermal_device 8250_dw processor_thermal_rfim libarc4 processor_thermal_mbox i2c_algo_bit processor_thermal_rapl mei_me intel_rapl_common fb_sys_fops soundcore mei syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt intel_pch_thermal intel_soc_dts_iosf mac_hid elan_i2c ideapad_laptop sparse_keymap int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel acpi_pad acpi_tad sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj hid_generic usbhid crc32_pclmul nvme intel_lpss_pci intel_lpss xhci_pci ahci r8169 i2c_hid i2c_i801 idma64 nvme_core i2c_smbus realtek xhci_pci_renesas libahci virt_dma hid wmi video pinctrl_cannonlake
 [  711.969906] CPU: 8 PID: 282 Comm: kworker/u24:6 Tainted: G        W         5.11.0-41-generic #45~20.04.1-Ubuntu
 [  711.969908] Hardware name: LENOVO 81LK/LNVNB161216, BIOS BGCN34WW 05/21/2021
 [  711.969910] Workqueue: phy0 ieee80211_scan_work [mac80211]
 [  711.969949] RIP: 0010:rtw_dbi_read8.constprop.0+0xaa/0xc0 [rtw88_pci]
 [  711.969953] Code: 03 00 00 48 8b 40 50 e8 04 75 70 fc 5b 41 5c 41 88 45 00 31 c0 41 5d 5d c3 be 19 07 00 00 48 c7 c7 d0 d6 6f c0 e8 1c b9 49 fc <0f> 0b b8 fb ff ff ff 5b 41 5c 41 5d 5d c3 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00
 [  711.969955] RSP: 0018:ffff986fc0dcfc98 EFLAGS: 00010282
 [  711.969957] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 0000000000000027
 [  711.969958] RDX: 0000000000000027 RSI: 00000000ffffdfff RDI: ffff8c871e418ac8
 [  711.969960] RBP: ffff986fc0dcfcb0 R08: ffff8c871e418ac0 R09: ffff986fc0dcfa58
 [  711.969961] R10: 0000000000000001 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffff8c83c3bf1f20
 [  711.969962] R13: ffff986fc0dcfccf R14: ffff8c83c3bf62f0 R15: 0000000000000000
 [  711.969964] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff8c871e400000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
 [  711.969965] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
 [  711.969967] CR2: 00007f44227f7008 CR3: 00000001b5c10003 CR4: 00000000003706e0
 [  711.969969] Call Trace:
 [  711.969971]  rtw_pci_link_ps+0x54/0x90 [rtw88_pci]
 [  711.969975]  ? rtw_core_stop+0xd2/0xe0 [rtw88_core]
 [  711.969984]  rtw_enter_ips+0x3e/0x50 [rtw88_core]
 [  711.969993]  rtw_ops_config+0xd3/0xe0 [rtw88_core]
 [  711.970001]  ieee80211_hw_config+0x99/0x3e0 [mac80211]
 [  711.970030]  ieee80211_recalc_idle+0x27/0x30 [mac80211]
 [  711.970063]  __ieee80211_scan_completed+0x14f/0x460 [mac80211]
 [  711.970091]  ieee80211_scan_work+0x128/0x590 [mac80211]
 [  711.970120]  ? __switch_to_asm+0x36/0x70
 [  711.970125]  process_one_work+0x220/0x3c0
 [  711.970127]  worker_thread+0x4d/0x3f0
 [  711.970129]  ? process_one_work+0x3c0/0x3c0
 [  711.970131]  kthread+0x12b/0x150
 [  711.970134]  ? set_kthread_struct+0x40/0x40
 [  711.970137]  ret_from_fork+0x22/0x30
 [  711.970140] ---[ end trace 74da5af69e3aa44e ]---
 [  711.970142] rtw_8821ce 0000:07:00.0: failed to read ASPM, ret=-5
 [  767.110014] ------------[ cut here ]------------
 [  767.110020] failed to read DBI register, addr=0x0719
 [  767.110084] WARNING: CPU: 7 PID: 845 at drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtw88/pci.c:1174 rtw_dbi_read8.constprop.0+0xaa/0xc0 [rtw88_pci]
 [  767.110106] Modules linked in: ipheth apple_mfi_fastcharge ccm rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_sof snd_hda_codec_generic snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_soc_hdac_hda x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_hda_codec_hdmi coretemp snd_soc_acpi ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel mei_hdcp snd_intel_dspcfg soundwire_intel kvm_intel soundwire_generic_allocation intel_rapl_msr soundwire_cadence snd_hda_codec kvm snd_hda_core snd_hwdep soundwire_bus crct10dif_pclmul rtw88_8821ce ghash_clmulni_intel snd_soc_core rtw88_8821c rtw88_pci aesni_intel snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine rtw88_core crypto_simd cryptd uvcvideo snd_pcm glue_helper nouveau rapl videobuf2_vmalloc snd_seq_midi videobuf2_memops snd_seq_midi_event videobuf2_v4l2 btusb mac80211 snd_rawmidi btrtl btbcm videobuf2_common btintel mxm_wmi
 [  767.110254]  intel_cstate i915 snd_seq drm_ttm_helper joydev bluetooth snd_seq_device videodev ttm snd_timer input_leds intel_wmi_thunderbolt mc wmi_bmof cfg80211 efi_pstore serio_raw drm_kms_helper ecdh_generic ecc cec snd rc_core processor_thermal_device 8250_dw processor_thermal_rfim libarc4 processor_thermal_mbox i2c_algo_bit processor_thermal_rapl mei_me intel_rapl_common fb_sys_fops soundcore mei syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt intel_pch_thermal intel_soc_dts_iosf mac_hid elan_i2c ideapad_laptop sparse_keymap int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel acpi_pad acpi_tad sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj hid_generic usbhid crc32_pclmul nvme intel_lpss_pci intel_lpss xhci_pci ahci r8169 i2c_hid i2c_i801 idma64 nvme_core i2c_smbus realtek xhci_pci_renesas libahci virt_dma hid wmi video pinctrl_cannonlake
 [  767.110425] CPU: 7 PID: 845 Comm: wpa_supplicant Tainted: G        W         5.11.0-41-generic #45~20.04.1-Ubuntu
 [  767.110434] Hardware name: LENOVO 81LK/LNVNB161216, BIOS BGCN34WW 05/21/2021
 [  767.110438] RIP: 0010:rtw_dbi_read8.constprop.0+0xaa/0xc0 [rtw88_pci]
 [  767.110450] Code: 03 00 00 48 8b 40 50 e8 04 75 70 fc 5b 41 5c 41 88 45 00 31 c0 41 5d 5d c3 be 19 07 00 00 48 c7 c7 d0 d6 6f c0 e8 1c b9 49 fc <0f> 0b b8 fb ff ff ff 5b 41 5c 41 5d 5d c3 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00
 [  767.110456] RSP: 0018:ffff986fc17137c8 EFLAGS: 00010282
 [  767.110464] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 0000000000000027
 [  767.110468] RDX: 0000000000000027 RSI: 00000000ffffdfff RDI: ffff8c871e3d8ac8
 [  767.110473] RBP: ffff986fc17137e0 R08: ffff8c871e3d8ac0 R09: ffff986fc1713588
 [  767.110477] R10: 0000000000000001 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffff8c83c3bf1f20
 [  767.110481] R13: ffff986fc17137ff R14: ffff8c83c3bf62f0 R15: 0000000000000000
 [  767.110486] FS:  00007f7cd0a4a140(0000) GS:ffff8c871e3c0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
 [  767.110492] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
 [  767.110497] CR2: 00007ff41f160000 CR3: 000000010aff4001 CR4: 00000000003706e0
 [  767.110502] Call Trace:
 [  767.110509]  rtw_pci_link_ps+0x54/0x90 [rtw88_pci]
 [  767.110522]  rtw_leave_ips+0x1f/0x80 [rtw88_core]
 [  767.110559]  rtw_ops_config+0xa3/0xe0 [rtw88_core]
 [  767.110586]  ieee80211_hw_config+0x99/0x3e0 [mac80211]
 [  767.110689]  ieee80211_recalc_idle+0x27/0x30 [mac80211]
 [  767.110800]  __ieee80211_start_scan+0x376/0x740 [mac80211]
 [  767.110901]  ieee80211_request_scan+0x30/0x50 [mac80211]
 [  767.111002]  ieee80211_scan+0x5c/0xa0 [mac80211]
 [  767.111116]  cfg80211_scan+0x1a5/0x250 [cfg80211]
 [  767.111225]  nl80211_trigger_scan+0x55c/0x660 [cfg80211]
 [  767.111335]  genl_family_rcv_msg_doit.isra.0+0xec/0x150
 [  767.111352]  genl_rcv_msg+0xe5/0x1e0
 [  767.111360]  ? nl80211_send_scan_start+0xa0/0xa0 [cfg80211]
 [  767.111473]  ? genl_family_rcv_msg_doit.isra.0+0x150/0x150
 [  767.111482]  netlink_rcv_skb+0x55/0x100
 [  767.111492]  genl_rcv+0x29/0x40
 [  767.111500]  netlink_unicast+0x1a8/0x250
 [  767.111508]  netlink_sendmsg+0x221/0x440
 [  767.111518]  sock_sendmsg+0x65/0x70
 [  767.111527]  ____sys_sendmsg+0x218/0x290
 [  767.111533]  ? copy_msghdr_from_user+0x5c/0x90
 [  767.111543]  ___sys_sendmsg+0x81/0xc0
 [  767.111552]  ? __check_object_size+0x4d/0x150
 [  767.111559]  ? _copy_to_user+0x31/0x50
 [  767.111569]  ? sock_getsockopt+0x11a/0xc70
 [  767.111576]  ? unix_ioctl+0x9c/0x180
 [  767.111588]  ? sock_do_ioctl+0x43/0x140
 [  767.111594]  ? __cgroup_bpf_run_filter_setsockopt+0xb6/0x3d0
 [  767.111607]  ? __cgroup_bpf_run_filter_getsockopt+0xb4/0x3c0
 [  767.111617]  ? _cond_resched+0x19/0x30
 [  767.111626]  __sys_sendmsg+0x62/0xb0
 [  767.111635]  ? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x3d/0x1a0
 [  767.111644]  __x64_sys_sendmsg+0x1f/0x30
 [  767.111651]  do_syscall_64+0x38/0x90
 [  767.111660]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
 [  767.111671] RIP: 0033:0x7f7cd0dda747
 [  767.111677] Code: 64 89 02 48 c7 c0 ff ff ff ff eb bb 0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa 64 8b 04 25 18 00 00 00 85 c0 75 10 b8 2e 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 51 c3 48 83 ec 28 89 54 24 1c 48 89 74 24 10
 [  767.111683] RSP: 002b:00007fffe28e0348 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 000000000000002e
 [  767.111691] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 000055c7abe99650 RCX: 00007f7cd0dda747
 [  767.111695] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 00007fffe28e0380 RDI: 0000000000000006
 [  767.111699] RBP: 000055c7abecd870 R08: 0000000000000004 R09: 00007f7cd0ea2b80
 [  767.111703] R10: 00007fffe28e0454 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 000055c7abe99560
 [  767.111707] R13: 00007fffe28e0380 R14: 00007fffe28e0454 R15: 000055c7abece780
 [  767.111715] ---[ end trace 74da5af69e3aa44f ]---
 [  767.111722] rtw_8821ce 0000:07:00.0: failed to read ASPM, ret=-5
 [  769.111816] rtw_8821ce 0000:07:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
 [  769.111824] rtw_8821ce 0000:07:00.0: mac power on failed
 [  769.111826] rtw_8821ce 0000:07:00.0: failed to power on mac
 [  769.111828] rtw_8821ce 0000:07:00.0: leave idle state failed
 [  769.111986] rtw_8821ce 0000:07:00.0: failed to leave ips state
 [  769.111989] rtw_8821ce 0000:07:00.0: failed to leave idle state
 [  774.960463] rtw_8821ce 0000:07:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
 [  774.960742] ------------[ cut here ]------------
 [  774.960743] failed to read DBI register, addr=0x0719
 [  774.960767] WARNING: CPU: 9 PID: 281 at drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtw88/pci.c:1174 rtw_dbi_read8.constprop.0+0xaa/0xc0 [rtw88_pci]
```

There is around 2000 lines of similar content.

`$ dmesg | grep -i firmware` returns nothing. Currently, the wifi has already dropped and I am connected with a cable.

I will be grateful for your help with stabilizing the WiFi connection.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1365111/732775

This answer should help you.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to work now.

Comment: I haven't used Linux for a while but now I see that the problem still occurs. So it seems that that the fix didn't work or it broke again.
The only thing I did in the meantime, was to do some automatic updates and fix the time shift dual boot issue with the `sudo timedatectl set-local-rtc 1` command. But I suppose that wouldn't contribute to the problem?

Comment: Sorry for such a late reply. I'm not really sure. Have you tried the same steps after fixing the time shift issue? One other cause *could* be windows somehow messing with the wifi chip, but that's purely conjecture. It seems this post is old now, perhaps you should make a new post. Hopefully someone that really knows what they're talking about can help you if you do so... D: