# Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.15.0-52-generic (x86_64)

Tags: apt, kernel, dpkg, dkms

When I try to install any package using apt I get the following error(s).

```
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/rtl88x2ce-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.15.0-52-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl88x2ce/35403/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package rtl88x2ce-dkms (--configure):
 installed rtl88x2ce-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rtl88x2ce-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. I have tried to apply the solution of [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1365111) post but when it puts the same error.

```
$ dkms status && uname -r
rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 5.15.0-48-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 5.15.0-52-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
rtl88x2ce/35403, 5.15.0-52-generic, x86_64: installed
5.15.0-52-generic
```

I don't know how to fix the difference between the the built and installed modules.

```
$ dpkg -l | grep rtl88
iF  rtl88x2ce-dkms     35403  amd64  rtl88x2ce driver in DKMS format.
```

I installed the rtl88x2ce-dkms from [this](https://github.com/juanro49/rtl88x2ce-dkms) Github repo.

Comment: Please can you add `dkms status && uname -r` [edit] your question for that.

Comment: Added, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: There are 2 modules but I  don't know which is the right one for your card. `dpkg. - l |  grep rtl88`

Comment: I've added the command and output, have I installed the incorrect driver?

Comment: `sudo dpkg -P rtl88x2ce-dkms` Then show please `ls -al  /var/lib/dkms/` There have to be a leftover from another package. But as I wrote no clue which is the right modul for your card.